# simultaeous programs

Tags: operating-system, simultaneous

I see that advantages or running programs simultaeously are that the user can run multiple programs and it offers better CPU usage, can any one give me an example of when it actually saves CPU time? eg busy waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand right, but when your emacs is waiting for you to type, you save time by scheduling another application while waiting for keyboard inputs.